# If there is no way at present for me instead of depending on bank interest , what should I do?

Tags: riba, banking

Assalamu Alaikum. I'm a student who's father died 5 years ago. When he was alive he saved his part of income in bank accounts.  Now I live with my mother and I'm the only child of my parent. As far as I realized it is a kind of riba because we are taking interest from bank, but I have no options either opened until I get employed. Our family is running through the bank money that has been deposited by my father. My question is, is it really riba in this case? if so, what can I do now?

Comment: We do not offer personalized advice. If what you require is a passive income stream from investing a capital sum then there are halal alternatives - Depending on where you are located some could yield more or at least comparable to the interest paid by a conventional bank.

Answer (score -1):

100% it is riba, first accept the truth.

Now come to your situation, is your situation worse than the family of our Prophet(P.B.H.)?

He was living in a hours of 4 x 9, hardly have to eat anything for days, only one cloth to wear...

Use the same money to do some business otherwise see the Quran

[Quran (2:275)](https://quran.com/2/275)

> Those who consume interest cannot stand [on the Day of Resurrection]
>   except as one stands who is being beaten by Satan into insanity. That
>   is because they say, "Trade is [just] like interest." But Allah has
>   permitted trade and has forbidden interest. So whoever has received an
>   admonition from his Lord and desists may have what is past, and his
>   affair rests with Allah . But whoever returns to [dealing in interest
>   or usury] - those are the companions of the Fire; they will abide
>   eternally therein.

[Quran (2:279)](https://quran.com/2/279)

> And if you do not (leave riba), then be informed of a war [against you]
>   from Allah and His Messenger. But if you repent, you may have your
>   principal - [thus] you do no wrong, nor are you wronged.

Comment: Allahu Akbar. I understand this. To manage this, I need time. But I am trying. And I am scared for the current sins are counting and still I can not manage something.